# How to make boundary wall for SVG so that the animated image wouldn't go out of the SVG?

Tags: jquery, html, svg

what i am trying to do here, is that, I add a small image and it will be moving around the body.. But the problem is, i wanted the small image to be moving ard in the svg box.. I tried to take the SVG ID and let it append the image.. It will still move out of the  svg box.. I wonder, if i missed out some codings?

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var num = 0;
var interval;

/*var svg = d3.select("main").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);
*/



$('#add').click(function(e) {
$('#box').append('<div class="predator" id="predator'+ num + '"><img src="Pictures/PondSpecies/anchovies.png"></div>');
$('#predator'+num).css({
left: randomRange(500,150),
top: randomRange(400,150)
});

if (interval)
clearInterval(interval);
interval = setInterval (function () {

for (var i=0; i<num; i++) {
$('#predator'+i).animate ({
left: '+=' + randomRange(-11,11),
top: '+=' + randomRange(-11,11)


s /* Extra */
//if (x < 0 || x > w) SVG.vx *= -1;
//if (y < 0 || y > h) SVG.vy *= -1;



}, 100);
}
}, 100);
num++;
});


$('#remove').click(function(e) {
num--;

$('#predator' + num).remove();

if (num == 0 && interval)
clearInterval(interval);
});
});


/* FUNCTIONS */
function randomRange(min, max) {
return Math.random() * (max-min) + min;
}
});
```

HTML body:

```
        <div id="box">
    <SVG xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="main" style="border:solid 1px #000000;width:515;height:474;">
        <image xlink:href="Pictures/PondEnvironment/pond.png" x="0" y="0" width="513" height="474" />
</SVG>
      </div>
```

Many thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: What's the css for your .predator class? I guess it needs to be absolutely positioned, you haven't missed this I take it?

Comment: oh, the css is:     
<style>
        .predator {position: absolute;}
        .predator img{width: 25px;height: 25px;}
    </style> 
Sorry, forget to put down css.. haha..

Comment: Ah, just made a fiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/DJg36/7/ So I take it the issue is that the predators are going outside of the box from your animate in set interval? In this case I guess you'll have to check that they are within the bounds manually and re-position as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your predators inside the SVG when animating, you'll need to check their new positions each time. This fiddle should help:

http://jsfiddle.net/DJg36/18/

Also, I don't think your animations were finishing completely, meaning they were starting to queue, possibly causing some confusions, so just to be sure, you should call stop() before animating again.

So something like this is needed:

```
$('#add').click(function(e) {

        $('#box').append('<div class="predator" id="predator' + num + '"><img src="Pictures/PondSpecies/anchovies.png"></div>');
        $('#predator' + num).css({
            left: randomRange(500, 150),
            top: randomRange(400, 150)
        });

        var containerWidth = $("svg").width() - 25; // Minus the width of the img
        var containerHeight = $("svg").height() - 25; // Minus the width of the img

        if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(function() {

            for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                var randomLeft = randomRange(-11, 11);
                var randomTop = randomRange(-11, 11);

                var predator = $('#predator' + i);
                var predatorLeft = parseInt(predator.css("left"));
                var predatorTop = parseInt(predator.css("top"));


                if (predatorLeft + randomLeft <= 0) randomLeft = 11;
                if (predatorLeft + randomLeft >= containerWidth) randomLeft = -11;

                if (predatorTop + randomTop <= 0) randomTop = 11;
                if (predatorTop + randomTop >= containerHeight) randomTop = -11;

                predator.stop();
                predator.animate({
                    left: '+=' + randomLeft,
                    top: '+=' + randomTop
                }, 100);
            }
        }, 100);
        num++;
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Andy